# Adding document reference to field

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I wish to add a reference to /user/ID inside one of the fields (called user, and is of type "reference") of my *charity* collection . As for timestamp you can use firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), is there something equivalent to this?

I did try by adding it as a string, but that doesn't work as expected.

--

In other words, how do I populate this, by code (specificly React Native)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appreantly, it is sufficent to do:

const userReference = firestore().collection('users').doc(ID);

and use that reference on push.